# How do I achieve this layout in react-native using flexbox?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve what I think is a very common row layout in most app using react-native:

[image]

This is what I attempted, but the Remainder section never expands in width beyond the text inside of it:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end', paddingLeft: 16 }}>
            <View style={{ width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
                <Text>Logo</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
                <Text>Name</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ width: 20, height: 20, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
                <Text>Icon</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set the `flex` attribute for the remainder view to expand.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'flex-end', paddingLeft: 16 }}>
            <View style={{ width: 50, height: 50, backgroundColor: 'red' }}>
                <Text>Logo</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'green' }}>
                <Text>Name</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={{ width: 20, height: 20, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
                <Text>Icon</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```